# Why does Xcode launch the IPad simulator when the iPhone simulator is selected?

Tags: ios

When I develop my project in Xcode 5.0.2 and "Build and Run" it, it launches the iPad simulator always when I selected iPhone Simulator ?  What is going on? How do I get it to run the iPhone simulator?

Comment: Did you try after quit both xcode and simulator?

Comment: Are you sure it is `iPad Simulator` or the `Retina iPhone Simulator` ? funny but may help you :)

Comment: ya sure.....i was run in Retina iPhone Simulator but it opens in ipad........

Answer (score 0):

Follow the image sequence and watch the result..
**Set the launch target**
[image]

[image]

**check the launched simulator details...**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These step May Help you for resolving this issue.

- First Make Sure Are you sure it is iPad Simulator or the Retina iPhone Simulator ?. If want to confirm please make sure with this line.

For iPhone (3.5 -inch) Simulator:

[image]

For iPhone (4.0 -inch) Simulator:

[image]

For iPad  Simulator:

[image]

- Make sure your project's Build Settings has `iPhone/iPad` selected for the Targeted Device Family setting under the `Deployment section`. (As if you try to run iPad project on iPhone will show you this Error - > The run destination iPhone Retina (4-inch) is not valid for Running the scheme 'Test'.)

if None work for you then please try to Quit both `Xcode` and `Simulator`. or you may need to reinstall you Developer Tools Again.

Comment: Hi.. i developed Universal app but it always run in iPad simulator  other than  when i select iPhone simulator.....

Comment: so the last we can do is to reinstall the developer tools.